# Vba Dynamic paste

Tags: vba, excel

I want to paste data in excel through vba coding, but the problem is I have a formulas section at the bottom, and for some reason I need to keep two blank rows above the formula section.

**For example**:  My formulas are in `Row 20`.  Blank rows are `18` & `19`.

And then I have data 40 line items of data.  So if I try to paste,  it will **overwrite** the formula lines as well.

Therefore what I am seeking any functionality in VBA to keep those formula lines "alive" and **insert rows automatically** by identifying the rows required for copied data to get pasted.

Comment: .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormula

Comment: Guess U didn’t get my question 

Comment: Well maybe I didnt - want to elaborate?

Comment: Ok so you want to dynamically move your blank rows and your formula rows? Is this what youre asking?

Comment: Yes....I want if i paste the data whether it is 20 rows or 50 rows it should first introduce extra rows so that my formulas section remains active.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Because you didnt bother trying I am not going to just give you the answer. However, I will tell you what you need to look up to figure it out for yourself.

1) Learn how to get used row and used column counts. Example:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

2) Learn how to move your formulas down based on the used range values you capture. In your example it will be +3 due to the two blank rows and then your formula rows. Youll most likely use:

```
 .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormula
```

3) Learn how to move current cell(s) vales around, specifically using ranges. You'll notice I use the Cells function to create my ranges. This will most likely be useful to you since you need to move dynamic ranges from point A to point B.  Example:

```
 Dim wb as Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 With wb
      .Sheets("Sheet1").Range(.Sheets"(Sheet1").Cells(1,1), .Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3,3)).Value2 = _
           .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:F3").Value
 end with
```

Now, once youve tried something on your own and come back with very specific coding questions, then I *might* be more inclined to cough up the solution. Dont bet on it though :P <3